# Dynamic networks import available in 0.8v is missing in 0.9.1v

Tags: gephi

In gephi version 0.8, it is possible to import a network and assign a date or an id to this network to represent a time stamp for multiple networks as dynamic network.

In the newer version, version 0.9.1, this property is missing.
How can we import multiple networks and assign an id for each of them to represent a dynamic networks in the new version?
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question: https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1546